# How do I call one method of an activity from another class

Tags: java, android

This is a part of my activity class,

```
public class StatusActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private boolean cFlag = false;

    public boolean getFlag() { return cFlag;  }

    public void setFlag(boolean cFlag) {
        this.cFlag = cFlag;
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                                      android.R.id.text1, messages);
        ListView listView = findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapters.add(adapter);


        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btnCustomerCheckIn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setFlag(true);
                cFlag = getFlag();


                Intent intent = new Intent(StatusActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                Toast.makeText(StatusActivity.this, "customer checked in", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }
```

this is a part of another class named as position

```
public class Position {
    StatusActivity statusactivity = new StatusActivity();
    public  boolean ccflag = statusactivity.getFlag();
    statusactivity.setFlag(false);

    }
```

when i am calling

```
statusactivity.setFlag(false);
```

it is showing an error. couldn't recognize that what is the error that i am getting. but

```
statusactivity.getFlag();
```

is working properly. any help is appreciated

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: Never instantiate an `Activity` yourself. This is the task of the framework, which will make all necessary initializations and call the activitie's life cycle methods. If you need an instance of the activity in your class pass it as a parameter.

Comment: `StatusActivity statusactivity = new StatusActivity();` is just plain wrong, instead of this, you should inject your `Position` object into that activity and have control over it.

Comment: We never create an instance of an activity by ourself. Its created by android framework work behind the scene.  To call activitie's method from other class you need to pass reference of activity to that class

Comment: @Janwilx72 its showing cannot resolve symbol 'setFlag'

Comment: @Henry  and Jay How ? i am new to java and android that's why. please help.

Comment: `statusactivity.setFlag(false);` cannot appear on top level inside a class. Did you mean to write a method?

Comment: i meant to set 'false'  to cFlag. could you please explain with an example code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StatusActivity statusactivity = new StatusActivity();
```

This is totally wrong because you are trying to create a new Instance of activity.
If you want to use "setFlag" method from other activity then you must create a static method inside StatusActivity so you can access using directly StatusActivity.

And If you want to call from any fragment of this activity then please get an instance of this activity by the cast from "getActivity()" to StatusActivity and use that instance for call "setFlag" or "getFlag" method.

You can implement like below in Activity.

```
private static boolean cFlag = false;

    public static boolean getFlag() {
        return cFlag;
    }

    public static void setFlag(boolean cFlag) {
        StatusActivity.cFlag = cFlag;
    }
```

and call from position class like below

```
public class Position {
    public  boolean ccflag = StatusActivity.getFlag();
    StatusActivity.setFlag(false);
    }
```

Comment: could you explain the right way with an example,it could have a greet help. thank you

Comment: StatusActivity.setFlag(false);  is showing error(cannot resolve symbol 'setFlag')

Answer (score 0):

you can not instantiate Activity class. if you want to call a method from activity, fist you should check that activity already running and not destroyed then by having the context of your class you just cast it like below then use its method

```
StatusActivity statusactivity= (StatusActivity )context;  
statusactivity.setFlag(false);
```

Comment: public  boolean ccflag = statusactivity.getFlag(); this code is working for me